# Is it possible to create a presignedURL for an S3 bucket with an incomplete key?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We're uploading images to an S3 bucket, but the file extension will change depending on what type of image a user uploads. Each key has the format of `img/{id}/file.jpg`. Each ID will have two images associated with it - logo and avatar.

Is it possible when creating that presignedURL, to just look for the key `img/{id}/logo` or `img/{id}/avatar`, without specifying the file name?

I believe I found something like this online earlier this week, but I'm not able to locate the resource.

So for example:

````
const avatar = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
            Bucket: myBucket,
            Key: `img/${id}/avatar`,
            Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
            ContentType: 'application/octet',
            ACL: 'public-read'
})```
````

Comment: I also noticed when I uploaded a png, the link to the image in the bucket downloaded a jpg. Do images upload as jpg by default? That would make this question irrelevant

Comment: No, you can't create a 'variable' pre-signed URL. For the JPG issue, you should set the correct content type (for example image/png).

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but if computing time is not a concern, you could generate two signed urls and let the client pick whatever fits best according to the extension they prefer. This way you can establish the correct content type at signing-time. The downside is, the client could upload multiple files if they want. One other option is to let the client upload whatever the file they want and using a lambda function you analyze the content of the file and copy it to the same bucket with the correct extension and content type *asynchronously*.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies

Comment: It's worth noting that creating pre-signed URLs is a very cheap process. It all happens local to the client, no network communication is required, and there are no costs or orphaned resources as a result of creating a pre-signed URL. It's just a local calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You need the full object key to generate your signedUrl. But thats OK, you just need one little extra step. List the items in your bucket, specify a prefix of `img/${id}/avatar`. This gives you your full key when you generate your URL.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html